# loading page directly when use route path

Tags: reactjs

i have created dashboard with login , trying to login with token based...i have logged in successfully...i have another component with status change page...when i tried to enter in browser using path....its rendering....how to do when the token is available in the cookies just render otherwise..do not render...

renderPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import Axios from 'axios';


class StatusChange extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            status_text: '',
            token: this.props.cookies.get('Token')
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { status_text } = this.state
        Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Token ${this.state.token}`
            }
        },
            {
                status_text: status_text
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.statusText === "Created") {
                    window.location.href = '/dashboard'
                }
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
    render() {

        const { status_text } = this.state
        return (
            <div className="Profile_feed" token={this.state.token} >
                <form>
                    <div className="form-box">
                        <h3>Status Text</h3>
                        <input type="text" name="status_text" value={status_text} placeholder="status" onChange={this.handleChange} required />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                        Upload Status
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withCookies(StatusChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply check weather the cookie is set or not? If it's not then return null (or do a redirect to 403). Try the code below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import Axios from 'axios';


class StatusChange extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            status_text: '',
            token: this.props.cookies.get('Token')
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { status_text } = this.state
        Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Token ${this.state.token}`
            }
        },
            {
                status_text: status_text
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.statusText === "Created") {
                    window.location.href = '/dashboard'
                }
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
    render() {
        const { status_text, cookies } = this.state;

        if(!cookies.get("token")){
          return null;
        }

        return (
            <div className="Profile_feed" token={this.state.token} >
                <form>
                    <div className="form-box">
                        <h3>Status Text</h3>
                        <input type="text" name="status_text" value={status_text} placeholder="status" onChange={this.handleChange} required />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                        Upload Status
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withCookies(StatusChange);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Have you setup some SSR for your react app?

Comment: Server Side Rendering . Are you rendering pages on server before serving them to the client in contrast to the default rendering of react on client's browser

Comment: Since you are using ssr, the cookie is set on server globally instead of client. This will cause the cookies to persist for all the users. So in your case, if some user has set your "token" cookie in the server, it will exist for your StatusChange file.

Comment: yeah its rendering like that only...when im in home...if tried to entered in the statuspage....when the cookie is empty...i can see that page

Comment: What are you using to setup SSR for your app? NextJS?

Answer (score -1):

i have used componentDidMount to load page..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


class AddProfileFeed extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            status_text: '',
            token: this.props.cookies.get('Token')
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { status_text } = this.state
        Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/',
            {
                status_text: status_text
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.statusText === "Created") {
                    window.location.href = '/dashboard'
                }
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed/")
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                if (error.response.statusText === "Unauthorized") {
                    window.location.href = '/dashboard'
                }
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { status_text } = this.state
        return (
            <div className="Profile_feed" token={this.state.token} >
                <form>
                    <div className="form-box">
                        <h3>Status Text</h3>
                        <input type="text" name="status_text" value={status_text} placeholder="status" onChange={this.handleChange} required />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                        Upload Status
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withCookies(AddProfileFeed);
```